# How to move my site from one AWS EC2 instance to another?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My site is currently hosted on an AWS EC2. The instance is in the free 1-year trial period.
The period is about to end but I don't want to pay any money. My wife has a separate amazon.com account than me, so I figured I should create an EC2 under her account and avail myself of her one-year trial period too.

But I don't know how to do it. I created an AMI of my current EC2. But I don't know how to export it such that I can pick it up and use it in my wife's AWS account. Can someone please explain?

All the instructions I have seen on the web just explain how to move AMI's between Amazon's regions -- not how to move them from one account to another.

Comment: This is not a programming question within the scope defined in the [help]

Comment: I disagree with @MikeW.
The Help Center says I can ask questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers". This is one such tool.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using "The Cloud" the Right Way™:

- You've automated everything, including deployments.
- You don't make edits on the live site, since the instance can vanish at any point.
- You don't keep anything important living on the EC2 instance itself.

If you're doing it right, you have every expectation that the server will fail and be replaced at any moment in time. But that's okay, because you *expect* server instances to be disposable, and you build your workflow around that understanding.

This is the thinking behind "The Cloud". So, I'm not surprised that there are no tutorials about moving from one account to another — since it *should* be inconsequential.

I hope this helps (although, probably not until next time). Then again, if you're running a t1.micro instance, isn't only about $15 USD per month (in US-East-1 and US-West-2)?

Answer (score 1):

You can share your AMI with other AWS accounts or make it completely public.  See [this article in the AWS documentation.](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/530)

Since your site is going to go away in another year even if you get this working, you really need to pony up some money if you want to keep the site going.